# Algorithm for finding combinations of an variable length subset within an arbitrary length set

Tags: algorithm, set

I'm trying to work out a method that would return a list of all combinations of a subset within a set.The method call would look something like `getSubsets(7, 3)` based on the image below, the returned output I need would be in the form and order of:

```
123
124
125
126
127
134
135
136
137
145
```

... and so on

The image below shows *exactly* how the counting order should go. I've been banging my head on this one for a day can't find a good solution. TIA.

[image: set of 7 with all 3 length subsets]

Answer (score 1):

To get the next subset after a given subset:

1. Find the largest element in the subset whose successor is not in the subset.
2. Remove that element and all larger elements in the subset.
3. Starting with the successor element, add successive elements until the subset is the correct size.

If step 1 fails, you have enumerated all possible subsets.

In C:

```
bool next_subset(int* subset, int n, int k) {
  // subset is a vector of k ints in the range [0, n)
  int i, j;
  for (i = k - 1, j = n - 1; subset[i] == j; --i, --j) {
    if (i == 0)
      return false; // No more subsets
  }
  for (j = subset[i] + 1; i < k ; ++i, ++j) {
    subset[i] = j;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Forgive me but in the above function, how do I know which subset I'm passing to it?

Comment: @Hal50000 You always pass the same vector, so each time you give it the one you got the previous time. At least, that's the simple way. In general, you give it a vector and it modifies it so that it is the next entry in lexicographical order. So the first subset is {0,...,k-1} (i.e. `for(int i = 0;i<k;++i)subset[i] = i;`) as in your diagram.

Comment: @Hal50000: Except that I numbered the elements from 0 instead of 1 :) But I'm sure you can figure out how to adapt it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know `m` of `getSubsets(n, m)` in advance, the code is just nested for-looping; eg. in Mathematica:

```
With[{n = 7},
 Table[{i, j, k},
   {i, n - 2}, {j, i + 1, n - 1}, {k, j + 1, n}]]
```

This produces all 3-subsets in the order you want, with `n` a parameter. Of course, if `m` is anything else than 3, the code is useless, specific code is needed for specific `m`. This is why I favor the flexible approach from @rici which is valid for general `m`.